# Having error with the output.xml file that is being produced by the Testcase execusion in Robotframework

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, robotframework

So I am executing Testcases(TCs) in robotframework by importing xml file which has the TCs. After execution the output.xml file is not in the proper format , because of that the xml_parsing script is getting confused with the numbers.
What is the reason behind this ?
This error is not RELATED to IE or whatever means i use to display the file
THIS ERROR IS BECAUSE THE ROBOTFRAMEWORK DOESNT WRITE THE XML IN BELOW REPRESENTED FORMAT

I have attached the scrambled xml file for reference

this is what i expect 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDqQ6.png)

but this is what i get
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7QzJ.png)

Comment: Don't use Internet Explorer. Open the file XML file in a text editor

Comment: Its not about that, for some execution the file opens proper in IE and the xml_parsing works fine. If the xml file being opened like this , the xml_parsing cant find the TCs ID and other stuffs

Comment: xml file shown in IE is how it is shown in browsers, because it is not editor that it will show you the way you wanted to look at it

Comment: I have edited the questions please for further clarification evaluate them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the carriage returns aren't working in the two files.

I'd recommend opening up both files in notepad ++ click on View ---> Show Symbol --> Show all characters